# Trouble scraping content of JS subpage

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble scraping the JavaScript content of this [webpage](http://haestirettur.is/domar?nr=10915). I've been using BeautifulSoup, which hasn't been that helpful for the JS scraping as I only get the following output instead of the text content of the JS subpage.

```html
...
<!--Comp:(1365)-->
<div class="com700_">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
tb_show("Captcha","/cr/haestirettur/captcha.jsp?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=200&width=300&modal=true","/cr/haestirettur/img/loadinganimation.gif");
});
</script>
</div>
<!--/Comp:(1365)-->
....
```

Where I execute the following Python code

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests as rq

url = 'http://haestirettur.is/domar?nr=10915'
r = rq.get(url)

soup = bsoup(r.content, "lxml")
print soup
```

Is there any nice way for me to gather the content of the subpage using Python?
Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to use `selenium-webdriver` to fetch dynamically generated content.